# how to display different images using grid function using tkinter?

Tags: python, grid, tkinter, label

I want to display the images in the folder using `grid()`. But when I tried with the following code, I got the output with single image iterated.

My code:

```
def messageWindow():
    win = Toplevel()
    path = 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\dataset'
    for r in range(7):
        for c in range(10):
            for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.jpg')):
              im = Image.open(infile)
              resized = im.resize((100, 100),Image.ANTIALIAS)
              tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
              myvar=Label(win,image = tkimage)
              myvar.image = tkimage
              myvar.grid(row=r,column=c)   
root = Tk()
button = Button(app, text='Images in DataSet',command = messageWindow)
button.pack(padx = 1, pady = 1,anchor='ne')
button.place( x = 850, y = 60)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run this code, after 5 minutes a child window will popup, and it will display a single image like this;

[image]

But how to get all the images in the dataset? Any suggestions are welcome.
Tkanks for your support!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said in a comment, you're putting the same image in every row and column of the grid. Here's how to avoid that using the built-in [`divmod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) function to iteratively compute the row and column for each one, based on the number of `COLUMNS` you want to display in each row based on the current value of `image_count`:

```
def messageWindow():
    win = Toplevel()
    path = r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\dataset'
    COLUMNS = 10
    image_count = 0
    for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.jpg')):
        image_count += 1
        r, c = divmod(image_count-1, COLUMNS)
        im = Image.open(infile)
        resized = im.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
        myvar = Label(win, image=tkimage)
        myvar.image = tkimage
        myvar.grid(row=r, column=c)
    win.mainloop()  # Not sure if you need this, too, or not...
```

Comment: I was not knowing about `divmod()`, really it helped me alot :) Thank you so much :)

Comment: @varsha: Knowing about `divmod()` isn't important per se, because the function is Python specific. However understanding what it does -- computing `a // b` and `a % b` -- is because that's the math behind the fundamental concept of how to turn a 1D (one dimensional) offset value into the 2D values (row and column) representing that position in a grid. It's a very common operation which is why Python provides a built-in to perform the computation quickly.

Answer (score -1):

You always use the same column and row for all images in the dataset.

Try removing the row and the column for-loop. and do something like this:

```
      c = 0
      r = 0  
      for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.jpg')):
          im = Image.open(infile)
          resized = im.resize((100, 100),Image.ANTIALIAS)
          tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
          myvar=Label(win,image = tkimage)
          myvar.image = tkimage
          myvar.grid(row=r,column=c)   
          r += 1
```

This should be 70 times faster :)

Comment: its displaying only in row wise, and if I increment the columns then it will display in diagonal wise :(

Comment: You will find a solution. Use `if`. When should an image apper in a new column?