# Python Tkinter Memory Game

Tags: python, memory, tkinter

I'm new to programming and need some help with programming a small memory game.

I have made a window with Tkinter and now I need to create cards that I can connect to randomized words. I have created code for randomized words but I have no idea how to create the buttons!

Can you guys help me? :)

This is the code for my functions so far randomord(ordlista) randomizes words and and lasfil() collects words from a .txtfile:

```
from tkinter import *
w1 = Tk()
w1.title('Memory')
w1.geometry("720x480")

def randomord(ordlista):
    import random
    randomordprimitiv = []
    for i in range(1,18):
        randomordprimitiv.append(random.choice(ordlista))
    randomord = []
    for i in randomordprimitiv:
        randomord.extend([i,i])
    return randomord

def lasfil():
    textfil = open('memo.txt', 'r' , encoding='utf8')
    textfil = textfil.read().lower().split()
    lista = []
    for i in textfil:
        lista.append(i)
    return lista
```

Comment: Hi @G.Dog welcome to SO, can you please edit your question above with any code you already have or have tried for this.

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

Comment: try googling for basics on Python and tkinter . start a beginner's tutorial ! :) then you ll surely come across creation of buttons and all !! try http://pythonprogramming.net/ . you can also try some video tutorials! happy programming !

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to the [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) geometry manager, and use one with equally sized rows and columns.

Maybe the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882249/how-to-display-different-images-using-grid-function-using-tkinter) could serve you as an starting point.